# Precise positioning of type – How to get font on its baseline?

Tags: html, css, fonts, position

I'm experiencing trouble with positioning font. With the inspector the canvas of the type gets shown like this:

[image: Canvas of Type]

With that much space under the actual baseline of that font it's very difficult to position type exactly. So my question is:

**Is there a way to handle this issue? Or more precise, how can I get the baseline to the bottom of that canvas?**

Comment: please add your codes.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you need, but if you want to implement the height of the lines -> use the line-height propertly(in your case `line-height: 1;` should remove the space you worry about), more on the property - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp .
And if you want to change the position of the text, I suggest using `flexbox` on the parent element (.parent{display:flex;align-items: flex-end;}). More on flexbox - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp . Hope this helps!